# How to integrate a system with a hamiltonian with non-diagonal kinetic energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

I have the following classical Hamiltonian for two coupled oscillators in the same molecule:
$$H=T+V =\left(\frac{p_1^2}{2\mu}+\frac{p_2^2}{2\mu}+k_pp_1p_2\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{2}\mu\omega_1^{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\mu\omega_2^{2}x_2^2+k_xx_1x_2\right),$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are momenta and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are displacements; $k_p$ and $k_x$ are constants; $\mu$ is the reduced mass; and $\omega$ is the resonant (harmonic) frequency. I need a velocity-Verlet-style integrator for this Hamiltonian. I know I can derive one from the Liouvillian acting on the phase space probability density
$$\rho(t) = e^{iL}\rho(0),$$
but I would rather not go through that exercise if I don't have to. Does anyone know a source that reports an integrator algorithm for this type of Hamiltonian or one similar to it? The real-life situation is two chemical bonds (O-H) vibrating with a shared oxygen atom.

Comment: what is the physical origin for the cross-term in the momenta?

Comment: it comes from the G matrix element G12 that describes vibrational coupling between the two OH bonds that share an O atom (G matrix is from Wilson, Decius, and Cross "Molecular Vibrations" chapter 4, it basically allows you to write the T and V using internal coordinates).

Comment: Related: [Which Hamiltonian systems are intrisically linear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457600/2451)